# how update one xib label from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want that update in player controller song duration of song(which is downloaded from the server) from the playlist controller.

Actually i m using avaudioplayer so in player i have two controller avtouchcontroller and avtouchview controller,and one xib of avtouchviewcontroller where all things (play pause next prev song duration).

so in avtouch controller i have a method UpdatePlayerInfo if i call this function then my problem is solved.

How i call updateplayerinfo(which is in avtouchcontroller) function from other(avtouchviewcontroller).

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand your question. Can you please rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

take a `iboutlet label in .h` file and `bind` it with your xib file
set the `property` of that label in `.h` file and `synthesis` that label in `.m file`.

Then in the class from where you want to change the label text set it using the `object of the above class`

EDIT: ADDED EXAMPLE
EG: In classA you have the label in XIB then `in CLASSA.h take iboutlet uilabel labelA set its property synthesize it` and bind this with the label in XIB. Then goto CLASSB take objct of class A and `objClassA.labelA=@"CHAANGEDVALUE"`

```
ClassA.h
UILabel *myLabel;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

.

```
ClassA.m
@synthesis mylabel.
```

NOW go to XIB file and in files owner inspector you will find mylabel BIND it with your label in xib.

```
ClassB.m//Accesing label in Another Class
ClassA objClassA;//ALOCATE THE INSTANCE
objClassA.myLabel=@"NEWVALUE";
```

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: U r right but Actually i want to update one viewController Xib from another class.

Comment: dats what i have said... like for example in class A you bave the label in XIB then `in CLASSA.h take iboutlet uilabel labelA set its property synthesize it` and bind this with the label in XIB. Then goto CLASSB take objct of class A and `objClassA.labelA=@"CHAANGEDVALUE"`

Answer (score 0):

You should create instance variable `UILabel *someLabel;` in target class and add IBOutlet property to it. (or just `IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;`).
Next step is to make relation (in IB) between displayed label and outlet.
Step 3. Profit (manage instance variable as you wish).